# linq2db, using DataConnection as abstract class

Tags: c#, linq2db

I am trying to use the `DataConnection` class of `linq2db` in an abstract base class like so:

```
public abstract class BaseDbDao<T> : DataConnection where T : IDatabase
{
    public string DBName => DBContext.Database;
    public T DBContext { get; }

    public DataConnection GetDataConnection()
    {
        return (this);
    }

    internal BaseDbDao(RelativityHelper helper, int workspaceId)
        : base(GetDataProvider(), helper.GetDBContextNew(workspaceId).GetConnection())
    {
        DBContext = (T)helper.GetDBContextNew(workspaceId);
    }

    public static IDataProvider GetDataProvider()
    {
        LinqToDB.Common.Configuration.AvoidSpecificDataProviderAPI = true;
        return new SqlServerDataProvider("", SqlServerVersion.v2017);
    }
}
```

I am then calling it up from another class like so:

```
public class EdMeDBDao : BaseDbDao<MSSQLDBContext>
{
    public ITable<EdMeTableRow> EdMeDatabase => GetTable<EdMeTableRow>();


    public EdMeDBDao(RelativityHelper helper)
        : base(helper, "123456")
    {
    }

    public List<RelativityWorkspace> GetActiveProjects()
    {
        using (var db = GetDataConnection())
        {
            var a = GetTable<EdMeTableRow>().CaseName
        };
    }
}
```

However, I can't seem to call `var a = GetTable<EdMeTableRow>().CaseName` as `ITable<EdMeTableRow> does not contain a definition for 'CaseName'`

`EdMeTableRow` is defined as:

```
[Table(Name = "NuixWorkflowCases", Schema = "dbo")]
public class EdMeTableRow
{
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I access `EdMeTableRow` class from the `EdMeDBDao` class?

Comment: `CaseName` is defined in `EdMeTableRow`. `EdMeTableRow` is something completely different than `ITable<EdMeTableRow>`. Similar to how a `string` is different from `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: If I move `public ITable<EdMeTableRow> EdMeDatabase => GetTable<EdMeTableRow>();` up to the abstract class, it compiles and I can access `CaseName` from `EdMeDBDao` but that doesn't help, as the abstract class should be a generic base for all inherited classes.

Comment: You should select row from the table. That row will be `EdMeTableRow` and then you can access CadeName property on it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please could you elaborate?

Comment: `IEnumerable<string>` is (potentially) "a lot of `string` rows". And a `ITable<EdMeTableRow>` is (potentially) "a lot of `EdMeTableRow` rows". So you need to specify _which row exacly_ you want the `CaseName` from. For example `GetTable<EdMeTableRow>().First().CaseName` to get the `CaseName` of the _first_ row in that table. -- Point is: _you_ need to specify your way to "Select" exactly that one row you want the `CaseName` from.

Comment: @Corak thank you! Solved it with that helpful explanation - many thanks.